# Why UINavigationItem shows menu button?

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, uicontextmenuinteraction

I have UINavigationItem with UISearachController;

```
#warning - addded UISearchController
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.preferredSearchBarPlacement = UINavigationItemSearchBarPlacementInline;
    
}
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleProminent;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

When I tap on the search button in the navigation bar then I can see a search field and some button with three dots(it looks like UIContextMenu, and after tapping on this button in log, I see "[UILog] Called -[UIContextMenuInteraction updateVisibleMenuWithBlock:] while no context menu is visible. This won't do anything.")

[image]

Questions:

1. Why can I see this in the navigation? (I don't add this)
2. how can I remove this button from the navigation view

Comment: "I don't add this" I  think you do.

Comment: @matt No, the app does not provide context menu items(actions).

Comment: No, but you do populate the nav bar with additional stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this element is named "Overflow support button". (thanks @Mozz)

If you add any item to navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems then you can see this "Overflow button" when open searchbar (self.navigationItem.preferredSearchBarPlacement = UINavigationItemSearchBarPlacementInline;)

In my case I have reimplemented rightBarButtonItem and this allows me to omit the representation of "Overflow button"

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.modeButton];
if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
    UIBarButtonItemGroup *group = [[UIBarButtonItemGroup alloc] init];
    group.alwaysAvailable = YES;
    group.representativeItem = barButton;
    self.navigationItem.pinnedTrailingGroup = group;
} else {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be happening because of navigation bar wrapping all the extra buttons in a context menu. This was a new feature introduced in WWDC 2022. You can check out this video for more details: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10069/